# Is there a python library that lets me take custom roots?

Tags: python, math

I want to take roots of numbers like cube root of 8 is 2 and 27 is 3. or the tesseract root? of 16 is 2. Something like sqrt(3(27)).

Comment: You can just do `16**(1/4)` or `8**(1/3)`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be functionally a math question rather than a programming question (understanding the relationship between roots and exponents).

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Nth root of a number is the number raised to the power of `1/n`.
Hence, you can just do:

```py
number = number ** 1/n
```

to get the nth root of the number.

Example:

```py
>>> 16 ** (1/4)
2.0
>>> 8 ** (1/3)
2.0
>>> 27 ** (1/3)
3.0
```

You can also define a function to do that for you:

```py
def nth_root(n, number):
    return number ** (1/n)

nth_root(4, 16)  # Returns 2
nth_root(3, 8)  # Returns 2
nth_root(3, 27)  # Returns 3
```